# printing second variable as many times as first variable

Tags: echo, printf

I have two variables. $a and $b in a for loop. 
$a has several lines of values. 
Example.

`````
$a=
````1
````23
````4
````5
````6
`````

and $b has a single value.
Example.

`````
$b=
````x
`````

I want my output as follows

```
1    x
23   x
4    x
5    x
6    x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -f;
for i in $a; do echo "$i $b"; done
```